# A thread per class in Java(multithreading?)

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question. I am planning on creating a program which would have multiple classes(for each object like cars/player/enemies etc), and I wanted to ask, is it a good idea to create a thread in each of those classes? I read that some Java VM support around 6500 threads, but would a mediocore laptop be able to support about 10-20 of them?

Comment: if your processor is not working in kHz then yes

Comment: 10 to 20 threads would not be a problem at all.

Comment: @Jesper assuming they don't execute heavy process

Comment: Yes you can create threads as per your program requirement but there also exists a limit to them, for better performance number of threads should be less wherever possible, always create threads when they are needed the most. And yes a mediocre laptop nowadays can easily support 10-20 number of threads.

Comment: @jhamon define heavy process?

Comment: that could be writing/copying a really big file, or moving shapes on a GUI if badly implemented/optimized, or stupid things like infinites loops, etc. I know that's a bit vague but it really depends on what each thread attempts to do, on your platform, on the other applications running. But yes, usually 10-20 threads are easily handled

Answer (score 0):

I think you should step back and do some more thinking/learning here.

You see, threads are a **programming mean** used to enable "parallel" processing on some level. They are not inherently "good" or "bad".

In other words: you don't just "use one thread per class/object" because you *could* do so.

You would only do that because you have a problem to solve where doing so would make **sense**.

And generally spoken: such an idea doesn't make much sense in the first place.

You see, the idea of "each object/class" having its "own activity" that "drives" them is addressed by frameworks such as [akka](http://akka.io/). And be assured: whatever you could come up with - such products such as akka would be more robust, more performant, more everything ...

The real answer here; as said: you should step back and first **understand** your actual requirements. And then you carefully look into existing technologies in order to design a reliable, robust solution.

As for example, there are such things as *Threadpools* or the whole [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) infrastructure that allow you to do things in parallel without the effort of managing Thread objects yourself. You should very much prefer to build on something like that, instead of just pushing "bare metal" threads into your classes.